# removing layers from a joined RDD and giving names to the elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on a sequence of joins between RDDs and after few joins it really gets confusing accessing each element from index. The below is a joined RDD for me. This is just a simple example. Actually it might get more ugly.

```
res41: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, ((String, Double), Double))]
```

Can I :

1. Give names to each of these elements in the RDD and then access them ?
2. remove the layers and get all the elements flattened as comma separated values ? I know flatMap might help but don't know how to use that.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flatten a nested tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699070/how-to-flatten-a-nested-tuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which programming language you are using, but in Scala you could flatten and name your fields by declaring a case class and mapping your RDD to it:

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("example")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val data = List(
    ("abc", (("x", 12.3), 23.4)),
    ("def", (("y", 22.3), 24.4)),
    ("jkl", (("z", 32.3), 25.4))
  )

  val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

  case class MyDataStructure(field1: String, field2: String, field3: Double, field4: Double)

  val caseRDD = data.map {
    case (f1, ((f2, f3), f4)) => MyDataStructure(f1, f2 , f3, f4)
  }

  caseRDD //has type RDD[MyDataStructure]
```

Comment: Thanks man !! This is exactly what I needed and I am actually working in Scala. This has been driving me nuts :(