# Transforming Array[((Int, Int), Int)] to Array[(Int, Int, Int)] in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have this type of data structure:

```
Array(((10359,60),80), ((10442,54),80), ((10440,61),90), ((10324,63),80), ((10286,35),100), ...
```

And I would like to get

```
Array((10359,60,80), (10442,54,80), (10440,61,90), (10324,63,80), (10286,35,100), ...

val maxData = mappedData.reduceByKey((x,y) => math.max(x, y))
```

after reducing I would need to get to the right format for printing and could
not find right way to do it.

```
val modifiedData = maxData.map(line => (? , ? ,?))?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flatten a nested tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699070/how-to-flatten-a-nested-tuple)

Comment: if you like my answer, please accept

Answer (score 6):

```
val modifiedData = maxData.map(line => (line._1._1,line._1._2,line._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for flatten.

```
 scala> val lol = List(List(1,2), List(3,4))
 lol: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
```

Calling the flatten method on this list of lists creates one new list:

```
 scala> val result = lol.flatten
 result: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch10s16.html

Comment: `flatten` isn't correct. The OP has tuples, not lists.