# Scala Iterate Tuple and convert to List

Tags: list, scala, loops, tuples

```
val a=((((1,2),3),4),5)

val result=...

Need to convert this to List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

In scala without using recursive loop.

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699070/

Comment: [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would either do pattern matching (which in this case grows very long), or use some custom flattening function, the pattern matching thing looks something like this:

```scala
a match {
  case ((((b, c), d), e), f) => List(b, c, d, e, f)
}
```

Pretty much boilerplate code. Now the other approach might not be as safe as this, but I prefer it over the first one, it's still safe though (for `Tuple2[Product, T]` like types).

```scala
@ import scala.reflect.ClassTag 
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

@ def flatten[T : ClassTag](product: Tuple2[Product, T]): List[T] = {
      product.productIterator.toList.flatMap {
        case t: T => t :: Nil
        case p: Tuple2[Product, T] => flatten(p)
      }
    } 
defined function flatten

@ // =>
@ val a=((((1,2),3),4),5) 
a: ((((Int, Int), Int), Int), Int) = ((((1, 2), 3), 4), 5)

@ flatten(a) 
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

@ val b = (((3, (1,2)),4),5) 
b: (((Int, (Int, Int)), Int), Int) = (((3, (1, 2)), 4), 5)

@ // I think this one works because of type erasure, should not have worked normally :)
@ flatten(b) 
res9: List[Int] = List(3, 1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Another option would be to use shapeless.